# AngularJS request interceptor causing trouble to my templateUrl view resolution

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, angularjs-http

I would like to prepend the value of my `<base href="...` href attribute to all get and post `$http` calls. I tried using a request interceptor as follows:

```
angular.module('curriculumModule', ['ng', 'ngRoute', 'curriculumControllerModule', 'directiveModule'])
.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Ajax'] = 'true';

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q) {
        return {
            'request': function (config) {
                config.url = $('base').attr('href') + '/' + config.url;
                return config || $q.when(config);
            }
        };
     });    

    $routeProvider
    .when('/view/:id', {controller: 'ViewCurriculumCtrl', templateUrl: 'view.html'})
    .when('/new', {controller: 'CreateCurriculumCtrl', templateUrl: 'new.html'})
    .when('/edit/:id', {controller: 'EditCurriculumCtrl', templateUrl: 'edit.html'})
    .when('/:curriculumId/workExperience/new', {controller: 'NewWorkExperienceCtrl', templateUrl: 'workExperiencesNew.html'})
    .when('/:curriculumId/workExperience/edit/:id', {controller: 'EditWorkExperienceCtrl', templateUrl: 'workExperiencesEdit.html'})
    .when('/:curriculumId/training/new', {controller: 'NewTrainingCtrl', templateUrl: 'trainingsNew.html'})
    .when('/:curriculumId/training/edit/:id', {controller: 'EditTrainingCtrl', templateUrl: 'trainingsEdit.html'})
    .otherwise({redirectTo:'/view/:id'});
});
```

**However, somehow, AngularJs also prepends the value of base href attribute to the templateUrls which I don't want.**

How can I prevent this please?

Comment: try with $('base')[0].attr('href') or $('base').eq(0).attr('href')  all in all it's a very ugly hack

Comment: Hi! I am not sure I am following you. The jquery does work. The issue is that Angular applies the inteceptor to all calls including the call to the templates causing: ̀`GET http://localhost:8080/bignibou/view.html 404 (Introuvable)`

Comment: Sorry I've taken a quick look but I'm wondering whay on earth do you do that ^^

Comment: It's doing exactly what it's supposed to.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base Maybe store your base url for your ajax request in a javascript variable instead.

Answer (score 2):

angular uses the $http service to load templates as well, so that's why your interceptor is mangling the template urls.  I strongly suggest that you modify the urls in a different way -- before you call the $http service, rather than as an interceptor.

A simple wrapper service should do it, something like:

```
angular.module('curriculumModule').service('curHttp', ['$http', function($http) {

   this.http = function(params) {
     params.url = $('base').attr('href') + '/' + params.url;
     return $http(params);

}]);
```

Comment: Thanks Geoff. Your solution is quite good. My original problem was actually to deal with the changing context path. I wanted to avoid hard coding it...